# Converting from .xls to .xlsx throws error "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC" in .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, console-application, epplus

I was using the following code to convert from .xlsx o .xls and it successfully worked in windows 7 system where it has 0ffice 2013 installed ,but failed in system 2003 server where it has office 2003 with an error `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`.I have used following code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = null;
                                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = null;
                                        try
                                        {
                                            app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                                            wb = app.Workbooks.Open(file1.Name);
                                            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
                                            wb.Saved = true;
                                            //.SaveAs(st1, XlFileFormat.xlExcel9795, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                                            wb.SaveAs(Filename: file1.Name + "x", FileFormat: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
                                            // wb.SaveCopyAs(file1.Name+"x");
                                            wb.Close();
                                            app.Quit();
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception ex)
                                        {
                                            wb.Close();
                                            app.Quit();
                                        }
```

when is used `SaveCopyAs` instead of `SaveAs` ,it simply converted from .xls to .xlsx but blank file.My real aim is to read excel file in c# and i have `EPPLUS` library but it will work only with .`xlsx` file not with .`xls`.Can anybody shed some thoughts on this error?

Comment: So why not run this on Windows 7 machine?
Not sure if office 2003 even supports xlsx files. 
COnvert on windows 7 and call it good

Comment: no that i cannot,for the time being,Do we have any method to convert

Comment: I believe (not certain) that you need at least office 2007 to be able to do this

Comment: Why are you converting _to_ a format that is over 20 years old? Supporting legacy formats will drive you crazy because there is far more support for the Office Open XML (xlsx) format. @dgorti is correct; 2003 does not support the newer format.

Comment: Can i create .csv file instead of .xlsx??